# running c# in a Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote a simple c# program that I would like to run using a Powershell file. I am brand new to PowerShell with no experience with it except for the couple hours I've spent trying to figure out how this is done. The program is a simple console program that should pop up when executed. Thank you for your help

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code in an assembly and then register it with powershell you can do this by using the Add-Type cmdlet as far back as powershell 2.0, the previous version of powershell did this differently.

So say your code in c# is in foo.dll you would use:

```
Add-Type -Path foo.dll
```

you can then call methods with syntax like this from your objects.

```
[MyClass]::MyMethod(10)
```

there is a good article on how to do this [here](http://ruudvanderlinden.com/2010/10/19/running-inline-c-with-custom-assemblies-in-powershell-2-0/)